# CodeBlocks wxWidgets project cannot find the wxWidgets directory

Tags: c++, user-interface, g++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm using CodeBlocks to work with the wxWidgets library, but I'm having problems with the library.
When I create a wxWidgets project it gives a warning saying:

"A corresponding Release configuration cannot be found in the wxWidgets directory you specified. This means that the Release target of your project will not be built.
Are you sure you want to continue with these settings?"

the wxWidgets im using is in the path:
C:\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1

the compiler: TDM GCC

using: wxSmith, Frame based

I reinstalled/build(with make) the library several times, compiler and codeblocks, variable in system path etc

I used:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1
```

to build the library

I'll try the things I find on the internet and in the error messages and update here

Comment: the question is whether you did build the library or not.

Comment: yes, i did build the library, i have updated the description with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right guys, i found finally the solution to fix this matter.

The problem is that codeblocks has updated wxWidgets project until 3.1 versions.

Now wxWidgets is in the 3.2 version.

Then based on the following content from the wxWidgets forum:

https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=42301

The codeblocks wxWidgets project has a script which have the instruction to search a specific version of the file -lwxmsw.

In the case just search for the 31u version. But the wxWidgets just has the -lwxmsw32u.

So do you have two options:

Download an acceptable version or edit the script as I did.

When creating the project, if you use the right mouse button, options will appear, and one of them is to change the script. And then will open the wizard.script

Around lines 340-350 will be the instruction about the specific file:

```
        if (IsUnicode)
            lib_unic_suffix = _T("u");
        else
            lib_unic_suffix = _T("");

        if (WxVersion == 0)
            lib_wxver = _T("26");
        else if (WxVersion == 1)
            lib_wxver = _T("28");
        else if (WxVersion == 2)
            lib_wxver = _T("30");
        else if (WxVersion == 3)
            lib_wxver = _T("31");
```

You can add a part for 3.2 or you can change the one for 3.1 to find the file for version 3.2.

If you decide to create a new part, you will have to mess with several parts of the script. Since I am only using the library for simple daily use, changing the string was enough to not get the mentioned error anymore.

So i changed to:

```
else if (WxVersion == 3)
    lib_wxver = _T("32");
```

My project compiled with no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

@GabrielTorraski,

From the description it looks like you didn't compile the library and just installed it.

Do the following (I presume here you are using MinGW compiler and it is installed and in the path):

1. Open the Command Prompt.
2. Go to c:\wxwidgets-3.2.2.1\build\msw
3. Issue the following command: `mingw32-bin.exe -f makefile.gcc BUILD=Release`
4. Wait sometime for the build to complete.
5. Go back to C::B and recreate the project from scratch.

However, I wouldn't recommend it. What you should do is to make a Debug build of the library and your application, so you can fix all potential bugs in your software.

Thank you.

Comment: To add to this answer, it's important when creating the project in codeblocks, the options used in the wizard should match the options used when building the wxWidgets library. Section 4.5 of [this guide](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PBfordev/wxpbguide/master/wxPBGuide.pdf) shows how to do that.

Comment: @NewPagodi, you are absolutely correct. Sorry for not mentioning that and thx for this addition.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i have used mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1

Comment: @GabrielTorraski, do you know the meaning of the options you used? Do you understand the difference between default vs supplied parameters?

Comment: yes i know, SHARED on for DLL, MONOLITHIC on for make just a single code pendency, UNICODE on is for text internationalization.

Comment: @GabrielTorraski, but do you when to use them? MONOLITHIC option make sense ONLY if you want to help with C::B development, since C::B uses MONOLITHIC build. Nobody else does. No one. UNICODE is ON by default, so it can be dropped. And SHARED means you will have to distribute a lot of DLLs with your software. This make sense when you do the DLL yourself to multiple versions of wxWidgets to be loaded. Otherwise it should be off to simplify distribution.

Comment: And UNICODE is not for i18n. You can internationalized youapp even without it. What this option does is its include different locals and fonts/keyboards so users can work with UNICODE characters. Read about online - Google is you friend. Try "UNICODE vs ASCII".

Comment: BTW, using release build of the library is not a good idea. You will be missing all debugging info and a possibility of stepping thru the code to find a possible issue. Unless you are B. Stroustrup or L. Torvalds I suggest using Debug build of everything 

Comment: And last but not least- make sure that wxWidgets build settings and your application build settings are in perfect match.